# ASP Core convert PDF pages to images

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to figure out if its possible to convert PDF document into a series of images.
Currently looking to migrate from ASP.NET 4.6 to ASP.CORE and this is so far the roadbloack to it.
I cannot seem to find any working examples for ASP Core of this currently.

Appreciate any help i can get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Docnet](https://github.com/GowenGit/docnet),

Here is an example code from project:

```
private static byte[] GetModifiedImage(IPageReader pageReader)
{
    var rawBytes = pageReader.GetImage();

    var width = pageReader.GetPageWidth();
    var height = pageReader.GetPageHeight();

    var characters = pageReader.GetCharacters();

    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        bmp.AddBytes(rawBytes);

        bmp.DrawRectangles(characters);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps
Cheers

Comment: how to use pdf path in it ?

Comment: Take a look at here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905169/how-to-convert-pdf-files-to-images)