# How to save a PDF as an image with C#/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, pdf

I'm currently working on a Unity project and I need to be able to open a PDF received from an API call. I'm able to download the PDF just fine, but now I need to convert it to an image so I can display it as a texture in Unity (I'm aware there's a PDF viewer on the asset store but I'm not willing to spend the money for this project).
My question is, how can I do this? It seems very easy to do with Javascript with the PDF.js library, however I'm not sure how I'd execute Javascript code within C#.
I'm looking for something along the lines of opening the already downloaded PDF in the browser, converting it to an image, and then using this image in my C# code.
Any advice on how I could go about this?

Comment: Is this for WebGL?

Comment: You could try your luck at [How to convert PDF files to images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905169/how-to-convert-pdf-files-to-images)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the C# .NET [IronPDF](https://ironpdf.com/) Library to achieve this easily. Simply create a ChromePdfRenderer using C# then create Bitmaps from an [input PDF](https://ironpdf.com/downloads/convert-pdf-image-csharp-sof.zip).

Simply return each page as an image as shown in the last line and now every page is a seperate JPG/PNG file.

```
using IronPdf;

var Renderer = new IronPdf.ChromePdfRenderer();

PdfDocument Pdf = new PdfDocument("inputexample.pdf");

System.Drawing.Bitmap[] pageImages = Pdf.ToBitmap();

Pdf.RasterizeToImageFiles(@"thumbnail_*.jpg");
```

A full code example can be found [here](https://ironpdf.com/examples/rasterize-a-pdf-to-images/).